# R: Filling a column based on the value of another column in dataframe

Tags: r

I want to map/join data values in DF2 to DF1

```
DF1 <- data.frame(match_col = c("apple", "apple", "apple", "banana", "banana","orange",))

DF2 <- data.frame(match_col = c("apple", "banana", "orange"), value = c(13,4,8))
```

I want the final data frame to look like:

### apple | 13

### apple | 13

### apple | 13

### banana | 4

### orange | 8

Comment: `dplyr::left_join(DF1, DF2)` or `merge(DF1, DF2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `merge()` function to join two data based on matching column:

```
df_merged <- merge(DF1, DF2, by = "match_col")
df_merged
  match_col value
1     apple    13
2     apple    13
3     apple    13
4    banana     4
5    banana     4
6    orange     8
```